# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DateOffset' forecasting error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, arima

Please help me in solving this error. It is being used to forecast 23
My lines of code goes

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
future_dates=[df.index[-1]+ DateOffset(months=x)for x in range(0,24)]
future_datest_df=pd.DataFrame(index=future_dates[1:],columns=df.columns)

future_datest_df.tail()

future_df=pd.concat([df,future_datest_df])

future_df['forecast'] = results.predict(start = 104, end = 120, dynamic= True)
future_df[['value', 'forecast']].plot(figsize=(12, 8))
```

I am getting this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DateOffset'

This is arising from the line

> future_dates=[df.index[-1]+ DateOffset(months=x)for x in range(0,24)]

The dataframe
[image: Dataframe]

Comment: What is the format of df.index? Could you show a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: The value of df.index[-1]  is 372

Comment: I have updated the question with a snap of the dataframe

Comment: Your index is integer-format. so in your 2nd line, you would only need `df.index[-1]+ x for x in range(0,24)`